# Finding equivalent impedance with ideal transformer

Tags: transformer, math, mutual-inductance

I'm working on finding the equivalent impedance of an ideal transformer. I want to derive the formula they are using in the book and lecture.

[image]

Unfortunately when I try and get this equation by hand the third term comes out negative (I know that my example has the second dot on the opposite side compared to the example that derived the equation above). It mentioned in the book that "M" is always positive because it is being squared but there is a j squared in the equation that would mathematically make it negative.

[image]

Is there an engineering or math principle that I'm missing that would clear this up?

Comment: The direction you have shown for I2 is backwards, given how you've shown the coupling in the diagrams. Therefore, your equation (2) needs to be negated, and this cancels out the negation of the j^2.

Comment: @DaveTweed Okay, thank you! I see what you mean. So is my problem in how I write out the KVL for the second loop?

Comment: Yes. Look at the direction you show for the current, as compared to the polarity of the voltage source in that loop.

Comment: @DaveTweed I thought you could pick which direction you want current to flow despite voltage sources? It usually works out in the end.

Comment: If I chose current going the other way it would just make the signs opposite. Current would be going into the positive of the source so that would be positive, then there would be a voltage drop across every other element making them negative. Is that line of thinking correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. Given the direction of current you've chosen, you should have gotten a negative answer.